# Class object's variable level memory error detection

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind tool does not detects the following error in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Instrument
{
    public:
        char instrumentId[16];
        char symbol[16];
        char cusip[16];

    public:
        void Pack()
        {
            memset(instrumentId, 'I', 16);
            memset(cusip, 'C', 16);
            memset(symbol, 'S', 18); // This is wrong
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Instrument* ins = new Instrument();
    ins->Pack();
};
```

Is there a tool that can detect these type of error. When it writes to more than allocated for "Instrument" is detected by Valgrind. However this is not detected.

Comment: Note: Do not `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Then what about the memset?

Comment: @DieterLücking why not?

Comment: You can avoid these sort of errors in the first place by not using magic numbers, e.g. use `sizeof symbol` instead of `18`

Comment: #include <cstring>

Comment: Yes correct; Using the size of these errors can be avoided. But sometime these can be possible when looping and settings some values for even for arrays of primitive datatypes such as integers, doubles. My question is, Isn't there any tool that detect these type of errors.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should use a good static analysis tools.

By example, using [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/)

```
cppcheck tmp_001-98,11,14,gcc,clang.cpp
```

I obtain

```
Checking tmp_001-98,11,14,gcc,clang.cpp...
[tmp_001-98,11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:19]: (error) Buffer is accessed out of bounds: symbol
[tmp_001-98,11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:27]: (error) Memory leak: ins
```

And row 19, obviously, is

```
 memset(symbol, 'S', 18); // This is wrong
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.